# Write a program in java to make a circle move with your mouse

Tags: java, applet, jframe

I've tried writing it in first Applet and it worked but I used repaint() method just after drawOval line and it was flashing too much that I cant see..Please help me to fix it.

```
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class MouseEvents extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

  JFrame frame;

  public static void main(String args[]){

  MouseEvents obj=new MouseEvents();

  obj.go();

}

public void go(){

  frame=new JFrame();

  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  frame.setSize(300,300);

  frame.setVisible(true);

  addMouseListener(this);

  addMouseMotionListener(this);

}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {

}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {

}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {

}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {

}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {

  repaint();

}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {

  Graphics g=getGraphics();

  g.drawOval(me.getX(), me.getY(), 30,30);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's not an applet, it's frame
2. Learn how painting in Swing is suppose to be done (ie not by using `getGraphics`).  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

Start by creating a class that extends from `JPanel`.  To this, register a `MouseMoitionListener` to track the current mouse position.  Override it's `paintComponent` to paint the circle where the mouse moves...

```
public class CirclePane extends JPanel {

    private Point p = new Point(100, 100);

    public CirclePane() {
        MouseAdapter mouseHandler = new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                p = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }

        };
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.drawOval(p.x - 50, p.y - 50, 100, 100);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

Add this to your frame...

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MouseEvents {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MouseEvents();
    }

    public MouseEvents() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new CirclePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Your program is awesome and sorry for my bad programming mistakes Im new and I want to learn code without going thorugh huge books.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The huge books are what will help you from making silly mistakes ;)